# Magento 1.7.0.2 site loading takes over a minute to load

Tags: magento, admin, performance, mediatemple

I'm running Magento 1.7.0.2 on Media Temple GS. I have a maybe 3 products max in the site, no plugins, etc. All of the sudden today, it take well over a minute to load the page, several minutes to load the admin, etc. What could possibly be doing this? It was fine last week and I'm 100% certain nothing was changed, added, etc. Thoughts?

http://www.bellabooonline.com

Sometimes the site times out and shows the following:

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Comment: Is it a low price shared hosting account?  It could just be a performance issue caused by using a shared host.  Make sure all of your cache is enabled and enable Flat Catalog and Flat Category in `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Frontend`

Answer (score 0):

MediaTemple GS is probably not sufficient enough for Magento. I currently run 1 store and maybe 3 websites on a MediaTemple DV and it seems just enough for the traffic that site has.

You can try speed things up by [enabling cache in Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_cache/index), see if that helps. Otherwise I would suggest that you upgrade to DV if performance is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyse your template and check whether template code uses Cache properly or not.

Most of the templates are not very efficient and you need to modify code to effectively use Cache.

if it was fine few days back but not now then you need to check if cache has been disabled or is it still enables.

Magento is configuration dependent so you need to check if you changed some configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One of the drawbacks of Magento is currently its speed if default configuration is used. There are certain ways of making it run faster. The best one is to enable GZip compression by changing .htaccess file a little. You just need to uncomment part of the code. In my case, the speed increase was exactly 235%. Let’s start speeding up Magento!

Find the following lines in your Magento .htaccess file and replace them with the following code.

```
############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip
```

## Insert filter

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

## Netscape 4.x has some problems…

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

## Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip

## MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine

BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

## Don’t compress images

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

## Make sure proxies don’t deliver the wrong content

Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

## enable resulting html compression

php_flag zlib.output_compression on

---

you can find browse link here

[inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/boost-the-speed-of-your-magento/](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/boost-the-speed-of-your-magento/)